# check id in all tables have the prefix table_

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hey guys i have a problem in sql, i want to check an id in all tables have the prefix 'table_' i used this query but doesn't work.

`SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE  'table_%'`

Comment: Try `LIKE 'table\_%'`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah it works on phpMyAdmin but when i fetch the query with php it gives me result=0

Comment: well then probably the difference is in your PHP. So you'd have to show us that. Or maybe it requires permissions which the mysql account you're using in the PHP does not have. We can't fix problems with things we can't see. Your question implies that this SQL itself doesn't work at all. But now we find that that's not really the issue. Please try to be clear and specific about your circumstances from the beginning.

Comment: If you want to match a literal underscore, you should be using `LIKE 'table\_%'`.  But, if `LIKE 'table_%'` is really returning nothing, then it means you don't have any table names starting with `table_`.

Comment: What version and flavor of SQL is this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  i found a solution thank you so much brother.

Comment: @ADyson `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is an ANSI standard, and used to be used (and I think is still included) in Microsoft's implementation of SQL Server. In MS-SQL, the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views have fallen out of favor for the `SYS` views.

Comment: @ADyson The problem actually when i use sys.tables phpMyAdmin said dosn't exist so i turn into 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA ' to fix my problem.

Comment: @Shawn I just realised that and have deleted my comment.

Comment: @ADyson It's okey brother thank you.

Comment: @Y.ElKanfoudi "when i use sys.tables phpMyAdmin said dosn't exist" yes that's because they are SQL-Server only tables. Whereas phpMyAdmin is only used to connect to mysql (or compatible) databases so therefore it's easy to deduce that you're not using SQL Server. I suggest you make sure you're clear about which database engine you're using, and then look up the appropriate syntax for that.

Comment: Anyway you said you had a problem with some PHP code? If you fixed it already, then please either post your solution as an Answer if you think others might benefit from it in future, or just delete your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this query to get all tables having a certain column:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where TABLE_NAME IN (
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE  'table_%' and TABLE_SCHEMA='<your_db_name>'
)
AND COLUMN_NAME='id'
```

Not sure if this is what you wanted because the question is a bit vague

P.S: Running MariaDB

Answer (score 2):

Add a backslash before the underscore.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE  'table\_%'
```

without backslash
[image]

with backslash
[image]

Here's why:

> SQL pattern matching enables you to use "_" to match any single character and "%" to match an arbitrary number of characters (including zero characters).

Comment: This would seem to be the answer, but the OP mentioned that even `LIKE 'table_%'` is returning nothing.

Comment: Yeah we'd need to know the database OP uses. It's not clear if it's mysql or anything else.

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` sounds like MySQL to me.  But the question is not clear, and not really reproducible.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is part of the SQL Standard, and is implemented in a large variety of database systems. The query presented would work equally well in PostgreSQL or MS SQL Server, for instance.

Comment: @Phiter Yeah it's work but when i use it on another query the last query use just the first table.